# Show the identity $\overline{A\setminus B} = \overline{A}∪B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've come across this problem in a finals paper.

> Show the identity $\overline{A\setminus B} = \overline{A}∪B$

I've found the right implication, that is:
$$\overline{A\setminus B} \subseteq \overline{A}∪B$$ by taking a $\in \overline{A\setminus B} $

---

*Note: $\overline{A}$ denotes the complement of the set A*

I need some guidance on finding the leftwards implication. Any tips?

Comment: You mean equality? Use de Morgan.

Comment: Is $\overline{A}$ the complement of $A$? Then you can use $A\setminus B=A\cap\overline{B}$ and then apply the de Morgan's law.

Comment: @GregMartin Ah the title has not been updated to show equality, new to Mathjax so used the wrong notation!

Comment: @SangchulLee This is an interesting point! I approached the problem slightly differently this is something for me to note, thanks!

Comment: $ \bar A \cup B $ is true for all elements outside of $A$ or in $B$. $ A \setminus B $ means, all elements in $A$ but not in $B$.  Taking the negation from the last statement should accomplish the proof. Alternatively, use truth-tables.

Comment: @Incompl33t Thanks!

Comment: Please add an answer to your question and accept it; do not write “solved” in the question title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We wish to show that $\overline{A}\cup{B} \subseteq \overline{A\setminus B}$ holds in general. The approach attempted by the original poster (checking that they are both subsets of each other) is also a valid approach. However, we can solve the problem much quicker than this as follows.

**Step 1**

Observe that: ${A\setminus B} = {A\cap \overline B}$ and so we can rewrite $\overline{A\setminus B} = \overline{A\cap \overline B}$

**Step 2**

By de Morgan's law, we know that, in general, $\overline{X\cap Y}=\overline{X}\cup \overline{Y}$ and so if we apply that to our conclusion from step 1, we arrive at final result: $\overline{A\cap \overline B} = \overline{A} \cup B$ as required.

And so this is all we need to complete the proof.